# Play Framework - find Object with "Or" in the query

Tags: jpa, playframework

It is [possible](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/jpa#finding) to use "AND" while querying for Objects in Entity like

```
Post.find("byTitleLikeAndAuthor", "%hello%", connectedUser).fetch();
```

but is it possible to user "OR" while querying, like

```
Post.find("byNameOrEmail", name, email).fetch();
```

Thank you

**Fixed!!**

Use `Post.find(" name = ? or email ?", name, email).fetch();`

While using "where" in the query, it fails saying "unexpected token"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to use "And" clauses when constructing objects, but I'm not aware of a possibility in simplified query to use "Or".

However, play can be used in many ways. Instead of writing :

```
Post.find("byNameOrEmail", name, email).fetch();
```

You can write :

```
Post.find("name = ? or email = ?", name, email).fetch();
```

using JPQL syntax.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to use simplified query with or. To enable it you must change the implementation of `findByToJPQL` in the class `play.db.jpa.JPQL`. Wrote test and enhance the documentation and create a patch.
How ever you can use the [JPQL](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jpa#FindusingaJPQLquery).